# Prove $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ is uniformly continuous on $[1, \infty]$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove this function is uniformily continuous on $[1, \infty]$, so far i have;
$$|f(x) - f(x)| = |\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{y^2}| = |\frac{(x-y)(x+y)}{x^2y^2}|$$

and then,

$$|x-y||\frac{x+y}{x^2y^2}|$$

I am not really sure where to go from this point?

Comment: You need to a *uniform* bound on $\frac{x+y}{x^2y^2}$.

Comment: Do you really mean $[1,\infty]$? Or do you mean $[1,\infty)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $x, y\ge 1$ then

$$|x-y|\frac{x+y}{x^2y^2}\le |x-y|\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2y^2}= |x-y|\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}\right)$$
$$ =|x-y|\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}\right)\le 2|x-y|$$

Comment: However, the metric $\;\; \langle x,\hspace{-0.03 in}y\rangle \: \mapsto \: |\hspace{.02 in}x\hspace{-0.04 in}-\hspace{-0.04 in}y\hspace{.02 in}| \;\;$ does not induce the usual topology on $\:[1,\hspace{-0.04 in}\scriptsize+\normalsize \infty \hspace{-0.02 in}]\;$. $\hspace{1.34 in}$

Answer (score 1):

If $x,y\geq 1$ what can you say about the factor on the right?? Here's a tiny hint $x \leq xy$!